# How to set image with QLabel in Qt?

Tags: qt

```
ui->label->setStyelSheet("image:url(:/1.png); border-image:url(:/2.png);");
```

Why can't the image be displayed after run? But the border-image display normal.
It can display normal in Qtcreator. It can display image in compiler even did not run.

Comment: tried my best to edit but the last sentence just make no sense.

Comment: Could you improve your question as it is difficult to understand what the problem is. Are you able to compile to application ? Are you able to run it ?

Comment: Try putting `image:url(:/2.png)` to see if it isn't an image format problem (for instance a JPEG file with a PNG extension that would require the jpeg plugin dll when run standalone outside of QtCreator).

Comment: @UmNyobe Thanks very much to help me edit the question. In the last sentence i want to express the mean that img looks fine in the graphical editor, However, the img cannot be displayed when the app is run in the emulator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the `image` property is for subcontrol only (see [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#image-prop) ), while `border-image` is valid for labels.
Use

```
 QPixmap::QPixmap ( const QString & fileName, const char * format = 0, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt::AutoColor );
 QLabel::setPixmap ( const QPixmap & );
```

Like this:

```
QPixmap pix(":/1.png");
ui->label->setStyleSheet("border-image:url(:/2.png);");
ui->label->setPixmap(pix);
```

Comment: how can i load a external image? I men, when the image is not in the resource file.

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
ui->label->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/1.png);");
```