# Paint application Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a simple paint application using Qt Creator. I want to have a rectangular area on `QDialog` in which I can draw an image using mouse. The image format will be `QImage::Format_Mono` (Black and white, pixel indexes are either 0 or 1). I will use pixel indexes for simple image processing purpose, which operates on simple 1 and 0 pixel values, so `Format_Mono` is essential.

Now the application does its job, but the image (painting area) is stuck at left top part (positioned at `x=0` and `y=0`). I want to have rectangular image editor part at any x and y coordinates I want.

To create the image editor I defined a `QImage` in `dialog.h`

```
QImage image;
```

In constructor of the `Dialog` I have:

```
image = QImage(ui->label->size(), QImage::Format_Mono);
image.fill(Qt::black);
```

As you can see in above code, I have a `QLabel` named `label` in my user interface. I want to put the image editor part in that label (or do something similar).

I checked the `QImage` documentation, but could not find a function to change the position of the `image`. Or, it would also be good if I could find any other way to put the `image` (image editor) in `QLabel`.

**What can I do to have that feature in my application?**

**EDIT:** The created image editor part has the same size as the `label` (as it should be the case), but image editor (`QImage`) starts at `x=0` and `y=0` only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175438/how-to-set-image-with-qlabel-in-qt

Comment: @AndrewKashpur If I have a default image in resources, can I build an image editor on it?

Comment: i may be wrong, but i think it is bad idea to build editor around QLabel. What you are describing is not too difficult to implement using QGraphicsView\QGraphicsScene\QGraphicsItem. You catch mouse events in view, store modifications to image somewhere and paint QGraphicsItem according to stored modifications. I'm pretty sure somewhere in qt docs should be reasonably simple example of usage of this part of framework